# Word that encompasses a person's mood, activity, company, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a preferably short word that encompasses how a person is feeling, what they're doing, and who they're with. The list of things I want to represent will probably grow over time, so a somewhat generic term would be ideal.

The best I've been able to come up with is situation or circumstance. However, they're fairly bland words and also a bit long. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can get mood, company *and* activity wrapped up in one short (or long) word.

Comment: *Situation* is probably the word I would use: *Hello, long time no see. What's your situation these days?* You could abbreviate it in casual conversation: *Hey bro, what's your sitch?*

Answer (score 5):

The problem with catch-all words is that they tend to be bland.

***[Situation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/situation)*** and *[circumstance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/circumstance)* are good bland catch-all words:

> NOUN
>
> 1. A set of **circumstances** in which one finds oneself; a state of
>      affairs:
>      *<sub>ODO **Emphasis** added</sub>*

***[Condition(s)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/condition)*** is another relatively bland word that can catch all three elements of feeling, activity, and company:

> NOUN
>
> 2. The circumstances or factors affecting the way in which people live
>      or work, especially with regard to their well-being:
>      *<sub>ODO</sub>*

***[State](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/state)*** or ***state of affairs*** is suggested by the definition of *situation*:

> NOUN
>
> 1. The particular condition that someone or something is in at a specific time:
>      *<sub>ODO</sub>*

***[Status](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/status)*** is related to *state*, so it would work too.

The single common problem with all of these words is that they blandly capture many ideas in stead of capturing our imagination with interesting specifics.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest word in AmE is "sup" - a contraction of "what's up".

If you approach someone and say "sup", it is recognized as a greeting.

If you *ask* "Sup?", you are in effect asking, "How are you?", "What's new?", Where are you and who are you with?", "How are they (one's testicles) hanging" - and various other questions.

I'm sure an authority such as Urban Dictionary will give the kiddies credit for this - but, it's been around for eons.

Comment: Trouble here is that *sup* is a question. The OP wants a noun, not an interrogative. However, you could pervert *sup* to be a noun, though this is going off-label. I'm thinking "John was happy with his *sup*".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, ***mise en scene***  (noun): environment; locality

thesaurus.com

Your request is a heavy burden for a single word to carry and the greater the load the more general and abstract the term will have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [context](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Context) may fit your description:

> - the set of circumstances or facts that surround a particular event, situation, etc.

Comment: *context* is a good suggestion but it refers to extrinsic properties (...that surround...). The question also wants to include the intrinsic feelings of the individual.

Comment: Actually 'context' may refer both to public or private facts and circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

There is [**mien**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mien) though this doesn't really cover *who they're with*:

> A person’s appearance or manner, especially as an indication of their
>   character or mood: he has a cautious, academic mien

Perhaps **bearing**, or **demeanour** or **aspect**? Difficult to capture everything in one word.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a word that describes a person and their context on the continuum of their life, then *phase* is good. It also implies conditions that change over time.

*"At one phase of his life, John felt unhappy with his job and friends."*

Also *chapter* and *stage* work well here.

Of course, you could just go for the obvious *life*

*"John's life was good."*

We know to understand this use of *life* holistically, to mean mood, company, career, etc.

Comment: Life certainly captures what I'm after, but I feel that it's too broad (same with phase). I didn't make this clear, but I'm wanting to describe how they're feeling, etc. over a small period of time (e.g. an hour).

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of the person's **existential state** — a term that covers pretty much anything you might want it to.